# Linq search several properties of a class for a string match where some of the properties are a list of another class

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have the following class

```
Public Class Booking
    Public Property Account As Account
    Public Property BookingDate As Date
    Public Property BookingReference As String
    Public Property CCcode As String
    Public Property Destinations As List(Of Location)
    Public Property Driver As Driver
    Public Property EmailReference As String
    Public Property FlightInfo As String
    Public Property Passengers As List(Of Passenger)
    Public Property Pickups As List(Of Location)
End Class
```

From this I have created a list called `bking` that I want to search for matches.

I'm using a string .. `searchString` which is the value of a text box that the user is typing in and converted to lowercase.

I want to query this list for a match in any of the properties, so whether I type in an account name or a flight number or a booking date, the query will return all bookings that contain the `searchString` in the properties I'm searching. I know there will be some extra results, but that's OK. See the code below. The query works great and for the moment i'm not planning to run it on a separate thread.
My problem is that for the last three lines that are commented out, the properties are all lists of another class and i want to search a particular property of each of those classes for a match. For example the passenger's `.Name` property

I know I can do separate searches, but this seems very inefficient. Is there a way to search these list properties in the same query? The reason I ask is that the search is executed each time the user types a letter in a textbox that provides the value for `searchString`

```
Dim query = From b In bkingList
                Where b.BookingDate.ToShortDateString.Contains(searchString) Or
                b.BookingReference?.Contains(searchString) Or
                b.CCcode?.ToLower.ToLower.Contains(searchString) Or
                b.Driver?.Name.ToLower.Contains(searchString) Or
                b.EmailReference?.ToLower.Contains(searchString) Or
                b.FlightInfo?.ToLower.Contains(searchString) Or
                b.Account?.Name.ToLower.Contains(searchString)
    'b.Passengers?.Contains(searchString) or
    'b.Pickups?.Contains(searchString) Or
    'b.Destinations?.Contains(searchString)
```

**UPDATE**

In response to comments from @caiusjard I decided to add a very basic de-bounce so that the search only happens 500ms after the last keypress.. So while the user is typing in the textbox, a timer(set to tick at 500ms) is stopped and started whenever a key is pressed. Whenever the user types another character, the timer is stopped and started again. If the timer ticks before the next keypress then the data is searched.

```
Private Sub TxtBookingSearch_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TxtBookingSearch.TextChanged
    TmrSearchDebounce.Stop()
    TmrSearchDebounce.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub TmrSearchDebounce_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TmrSearchDebounce.Tick
    TmrSearchDebounce.Stop()
    If TxtBookingSearch.Text > "" Then
        BookingSearchBookings(TxtBookingSearch.Text)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you try anything like `b.Passengers?.Any(Function(p) p.Name.Contains(searchString))`? (You could use `p.Name.IndexOf(searchString, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0` for a case-insensitive Contains.)

Comment: @AndrewMorton suggestion will do and use `OrElse` instead of `Or`...

Comment: Thanks folks. I was thinking about `.any` and i also like the simplification in the answer from @CaiusJard :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be wiser to add this functionality to your class instead, and if you're going to be searching a lot of things, far more often than you are writing them, to implement some kind of cache. I'll do a quick intro to the concept of caching here using just 3 properties and 1 of the lists:

```
Public Class Booking
    'easily generated by clicking the screwdriver in VS and choosing Convert to Full Property
    Private _CCcode As String
    Private _BookingDate As Date
    Private _BookingReference As String


    Public Property BookingDate As Date
        Get
            Return _BookingDate
        End Get
        Set
            _BookingDate = Value
            _searchableString = Nothing
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property BookingReference As String
        Get
            Return _BookingReference
        End Get
        Set
            _BookingReference = Value
            _searchableString = Nothing
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property CCcode As String
        Get
            Return _CCcode
        End Get
        Set
            _CCcode = Value
            _searchableString = Nothing
        End Set
    End Property


    Public Property Account As Account
    Public Property Destinations As List(Of Location)
    Public Property Driver As Driver
    Public Property EmailReference As String
    Public Property FlightInfo As String
    Public Property Passengers As List(Of Passenger)
    Public Property Pickups As List(Of Location)

    Private _searchableString as StringBuilder = Nothing

    Public Function Contains(s as String) as Boolean

       If _searchableString is Nothing Then
         _searchableString = New StringBuilder
         _searchableString.AppendLine(_BookingDate.ToShortDateString) _
             .AppendLine(_BookingReference) _
             .AppendLine(_CCode.ToLower) _

         For Each p as Passenger in Passengers
             _searchableString.AppendLine(p)
         Next p
       End If

       Return _searchableString.Contains(s)

    End 

    Public Sub AddPassenger(s as String)
      Passengers.Add(s)
      _searchableString = Nothing
    End Sub

End Class
```

Your LINQ then becomes a lot simpler:

```
From b In bkingList 
Where b.Contains(searchString)
```

Also, because the class method implements a cheapo cache (putting lowercased versions of all its known relevant text into a stringbuilder) we can more quickly query it over and over. The cache is only invalidated upon setting a value in a property.

Note; that some of your properties are lists messes with this a bit, as presumably elsewhere you Get the list but then add an item to it. Really the class should control this with eg AddPassenger; you shouldn't make th lists public so any old external class can reach in and fiddle with this class' data members, clear them , etc

If you're after a quick way round this, expand the Passengers to a full property and set `_searchableString = Nothing` inside the Get for the list; even though getting the list doesn't guarantee it will be written to, it doesn't matter because it means the cache will still be refreshed if the list IS written to (and it still performs better on average even if the list isn't written to)

Comment: Of course! I should have thought of that - a bit like database generated properties in EF. Thanks.

Comment: If you find performance could do with improvement because youre searching thousands of items on every keypress, redrawing a UI etc, you can search for "debounce event vb.net" or similar - or implement a strategy where you start a timer and write the current date into a variable when someone starts typing, and every time they keep typing update the date. In the timer tick(ten times a second) do the math on the that date every time they keypress vs current time, and only run the query if it's e.g. 1 second later (and stop the timer). That was they can quickly type X characters

Comment: and the search only runs a second after they finish typing, meaning they will have typed a long string of "especially", and you haven't had to execute 9 searches along the way (the first few being very common strings of e, es, esp..)

Comment: I was just thinking about that :-) As it stands the search only takes about 80ms, but over time that will get much longer as more data is added, and I do want to make the program as responsive as reasonably possible as data increase. "Great minds.." :-)

Comment: For sure give a thought to the debounce then; you can always shortcut it using the return key for those power users who don't want to wait.. If you want to get really smart you can time the average milliseconds between keypresses for each user and wait 5x the avg before initiating a search... Overkill?! (it wasn't for one of my projects where the users ranged from super sharp multi outlett business owners right the way down to the very mature volunteer that "didn't get" computers)

Comment: Thumbs up.. I would stop the timer before running the query; it's pretty hard to see how timer.stop would fail but the query could fail (esp if it's a database) which would mean the timer would tick again and again..

Comment: Good idea, but tbh the class has quite a few more properties and I have half a dozen classes. I tried writing it as a database, but because of all the associations, the db was too slow, to I'm working with lists that are split by first character of a chosen property into dictionaries and serializing as needed. Its a single user environment and this way seems quick enough and far easier to maintain and update tbh. Thanks for the advice. Answer updated in a mo.